# Row wise frequency of each word in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, eda

How to calculate:

> frequency of each word, present in another column of same row/index, i.e.

| case_description_new | item_new |
| --- | --- |
| This row contains word_13 word_43 word_11 | word_11 word_12 word_13 |
| This row contains word_31 word_34 word_22 | word_21 word_22 word_23 |
| This row contains word_33 word_33 word_51 | word_31 word_32 word_33 |

Output:

| case_description_new | item_new | items_frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This row contains word_13 word_43 word_11 | word_11 word_12 word_13 | word_11: 1, word_12: 0, word_13:1 |
| This row contains word_31 word_34 word_22 | word_21 word_22 word_23 | word_21:0 word_22:1 word_23:0 |
| This row contains word_33 word_33 word_51 | word_31 word_32 word_33 | word_31:0 word_32:0 word_33:2 |

**Data**

```py
df_name = pd.DataFrame({
    'case_description_new': ['This row contains word_13 word_43 word_11', 'This row contains word_31 word_34 word_22', 'This row contains word_33 word_33 word_51'],
    'item_new': ['word_11 word_12 word_13', 'word_21 word_22 word_23', 'word_31 word_32 word_33']
    
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with comprehension and `str.count`

```
df['freq'] = [{z: x.count(z) for z in y.split()} for x, y in df.to_numpy()[:, :2]]
```

---

```
                        case_description_new                 item_new                                        freq
0  This row contains word_13 word_43 word_11  word_11 word_12 word_13  {'word_11': 1, 'word_12': 0, 'word_13': 1}
1  This row contains word_31 word_34 word_22  word_21 word_22 word_23  {'word_21': 0, 'word_22': 1, 'word_23': 0}
2  This row contains word_33 word_33 word_51  word_31 word_32 word_33  {'word_31': 0, 'word_32': 0, 'word_33': 2}
```

Comment: This solution works. Thank you. 
Making minor changes to your solution to make it easy to read & understand: 
df_name['freq'] = [{kw_count: case_description_new.count(kw_count) for kw_count in item_new.split()} for case_description_new, item_new in df_name.to_numpy()[:, :2]]